# Large scale application with GWT

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT (2.0.x) to develop a large scale and modularized application, but some modules have a lot of classes.

I'm facing a problem with GWT in development, because the DevMode it's taking a long time (processing) when I change every client-side class and refreshing at the browser.

My last option is to split more that modules, but I'm thinking to edit the GWT-DEV source code and "tell him" to do hotdeploy only on selected classes.

I have another option rather than edit GWT-DEV source code ?

Comment: Maybe you should think about testing each module separately? (ofc if you have multiple gwt-modules). And lazy loading (as mentioned in Jai answer) should also help.

Comment: Yes. All modules are tested separately.

Answer (score 4):

Try using GWT.runAsync() to lazy load your code. If you can load only those modules that you need. You can make fairly complex web apps using GWT which run very fast. Hope you are following the MVP architecture recommended by google. Any extra information regarding the number of your classes etc will be helpful if figuring out if you need to reconsider your architecture or not.

Comment: GWT.runAsync() will create another problem, with permutations compilation. The compilation will be slower if I split the code, using GWT.runAsync

Comment: You already are using modules. Intelligently done, you shouldnt see crazy compile times. Modules and code splitting are really sound practices. Not sure, maybe you should check your dev env, something else slowing things down for you? You should give more details, what are the times you are seeing... what is your dev platform - browser - os - gwt version etc. I have experienced some combinations of those really slowing up for dev mode.

Comment: Nice blog  Maybe this helps - http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/02/22/structuring-gwt-modules-for-large-applications/